# How get the array size using dynamic type

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am getting an `array` when I `deserialize` my `JSON`.

I can access the `array` with `foreach`.

```
dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (dynamic result in  obj.Results.output1.value.Values)
{
}
```

But I need to get `size` of the `array` to access the last element direct.

Eg.

```
obj.Results.output1.value.Values[size-1]
```

How can I do that?

#### Edit 1

I need to get for example the `"Y"` in `"Values"`

```
{
  "Results": {
    "output1": {
      "type": "table",
      "value": {
        "ColumnNames": [
          "I01",
          "I02",
          "I03",
          "O01",
          "Scored Probabilities for Class \"0\"",
          "Scored Probabilities for Class \"1\"",
          "Scored Probabilities for Class \"2\"",
          "Scored Labels"
        ],
        "Values": [
          [
            "-0.96624",
            "0.02918",
            "-0.44237",
            null,
            "3.25456957391002E-12",
            "0.000107838139228988",
            "2.76633869589205E-07",
            "Y"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Edit 2

If I print I get this `JSON`

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.Results.output1.value.Values);

[
    [
        "-0.96624",
        "0.02918",
        "-0.44237",
        null,
        "3.25456957391002E-12",
        "0.000107838139228988",
        "2.76633869589205E-07",
        "Y"
    ]
]
```

And the Count prints `1`

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.Results.output1.value.Values.Count);
```

I almost there, I need the last element o the `size` to access by index in the inside `array`.

#### Edit 3

I could get the last element with:

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.Results.output1.value.Values[0].Last);
```

And the array size with:

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.Results.output1.value.Values[0].Count);
```

Comment: `obj.Results.Length`? Unless it's actually a `List` (even though it's an array in JSON), then you'd use `obj.Results.Count`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: `obj.Results.Count` definitely works for the default configuration of `json.Net` - I've just tested it. Can you show us your JSON? Or write `Type t = obj.Results.GetType();` and put a breakpoint to check the type of `Results`

Comment: `Length` and `Count` I get AggregateException

Comment: I will add the `JSON` in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSON shows that `Results` is an *object*, not an array or list. What you're iterating is the properties. It's not a collection. It will be a `JObject`, which exposes `.Last`.

[See here for more information](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Last.htm)

You simply need to write:

```
dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var lastProperty = obj.Last;
```

Might be useful to cast to a JObject (or a `Dictionary<string, object>` as well to help with future issues.

```
JObject obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Accessing `Values`:

```
dynamic thing = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var t = thing.Results.output1.value.Values.Count;
```

Comment: I wrote `Results` to simplify the question, I add the `JSON` after. The array that I need is the size of `"Values"`.

Comment: @HaroldoGondim See my edit - it definitely works with `Values` as well.

Comment: But I almost there, please see my second edit in the question.

Comment: I could get the with                     `Console.WriteLine(obj.Results.output1.value.Values[0].Last);`

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] foo = new int[10];
int n = foo.Length;
```

you can get array size using ( `arrayname.lenth` ).try it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample, I can get the result of 100.

```
ICollection collection = new int[100];
dynamic obj = collection;
Console.WriteLine(obj.Length);
```

Comment: The compiler asked for a type than I added: `ICollection<int> collection = new int[100];` but I also get `AggregateException`.